# How can I merge my dev branch if the master is 8 ahead and 16 behind (8 ahead are useless)

Tags: git

As the topic states, I have a dev git branch that is 16 commits ahead and 8 behind the master. The master is 8 ahead, but the commits are useless and the source code is flawed. I need to remove them.

I tried to make my dev branch the new master and simply switch.

```
git branch -m master old_master
git branch -m develop master
git push --set-upstream origin master
```

But I received an error message:

```
To git@XYZ.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@XYZ.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

So what could I do now? My goal is basically to make the dev the new master or, go back with the master where master and dev where "equal" and then do the merge.

Any ideas?

Comment: Wy don't you just reset the master to the point `dev` branched off?

Comment: Is it that simple? Just to ```git checkout 123456``` and commit & push?

Comment: `checkout` is not the command you are looking for. You meant that you want to drop the 8 commits that master is ahead of your `dev` branch. So if you really want to kick them out you do a `git reset --hard ThePointTheDevBranchStarted`. Don't forgett to merge afterwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So imagine the following graph:
[image: graph]

You now meant, that the commits after the branch off of the blue one are not needed. So you do a

`$ git reset --hard 2`

And now you can merge in you blue branch with a simple fast forward

```
git checkout master
git merge dev
git push origin master
```

Answer (score 3):

**Note**: whatever method you try, make sure to "unrename" your local branches first, i.e. so that the *original* `master` and `dev` on your local machine are indeed named "master" and "dev," respectively.

While the suggestion to do a simple hard reset is a good one if you have not pushed the commits you want to "undo" to the server, in this case it seems that you *have* pushed them (if that is not the case, you can disregard this answer and go with ckruczek's answer, which will result in a cleaner history). Once commits are pushed to the server, they really cannot be undone unless you a) do a forced push **and** b) have every member of your team do hard resets on their end as well.

If you simply want to make `master` reflect what is in `dev`, the following steps will do it, without trying to rewrite history. First, make sure you have the latest from the server:

```
git checkout master
git pull
git checkout dev
git pull
```

Then, do a merge:

```
git merge master -s ours
git checkout master
git merge dev
```

After these steps, both `master` and `dev` will point to the same commit, whose contents equal what was in `dev` before these steps. Of course, you will want to push `dev` and `master` to `origin` after these steps.

Comment: Yes, as you noticed, I have pushed them already to the master branch (or someone else did). So the team is small, I think the hard reset is ok. I will move my code later that day in a new repo and do some tests. I'm to afraid to make something wrong that can not be "redone" :)

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out again david. I did t thought he really already pushed it because he said he derinitlly wants to get rid of the commits!! Good tip.